# Using CSS to Highlight Current Page

Tags: html, css

I want to highlight current page by using CSS, but somehow it doesn't work.  Please take a look at my code below.

HTML

```
    <body id="home"> 
<div id="mainNav">
        <a href="/Dashboard/Index" id="navIndex">
           <div class="circle text-uppercase">
              <div class="icon23X27"><img src="~/Content/icons/dashBoard.png" width="23px" height="27px" align="middle" /></div><span class="textStyle">Dashboard</span>
          </div>    
       </a>

       <a href="/samples/register/" id="navRegister">
          <div class="circle text-uppercase">
             <div class="icon23X27"><img src="~/Content/icons/samples.png" width="23px" height="27px" align="middle" /></div><span class="textStyle">Sample Registration</span>
            </div>   </a>

      <a href="/samples/search/"> 
        .........
</div>
```

CSS

```
body#/samples/register a#navRegister .textStyle {
    background-color:red !important
}
```

Comment: You cant use CSS only to do this. You will have to use a client/server side scripting language too

Answer (score 3):

The syntax is wrong. Use this way:

```css
body a#navRegister[href="/samples/register"] .textStyle {
    background-color:red !important
}
```

Yours is a worst example of having `div` inside `<a>`, which is similar to having a bottle inside some water, not water inside bottle, which is right one.

Comment: Thank you Kumar!  I replaced the code, but somehow it doesn't work, yet.

Comment: Please call me `Praveen`. Can you show me a live fiddle, so that we can check if it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Take your body ID, in this case `#home` and combine it with the id on the home nave element, in this case `#navIndex`:

```
#home #navIndex .textStyle {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Then you can add a selector for each of your pages to catch the current page in the nav with css alone:

```
#home #navIndex .textStyle,
#register #navRegister .textStyle {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Drop the `!important` it's only necessary in a couple of edge cases in css and should be avoided (I appreciate one of those edge cases is just trying to definitely make a selector show some visible effect, which may well be what you're doing with the posted css).

You'd also benefit from using classes instead of ids as css selectors.

Caveat:

It's probably better to render this in the html server side as the server can use the request URL to decide which nav item is current. That way you can just add a `selected-nav-text` class to your current nav span and your css becomes:

```
.selected-nav-text {
    background-color: red;
}
```

This is simpler, you can write logic once server side to calculate the current nav and css once to highlight it, then when you change your nav the functionality will come instantly.

Comment: Hi Tony Leigh, Thank you so much for your help! I try #home #navIndex .textStyle, the style is showed, but when I added more #register navRegister .textStyle, it doesn't show anything when I clicked on "Sample Registration" link! I wonder where is #register. I concern how CSS handle the current page.

Comment: i missed a `#` - however, you'd be better off reading and understanding rather than copying and pasting :-)